# How to return Observable<boolean> in canActivate on a guarded route in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to guard a route with a CanActivate class. The documentation I have read always has the `canActivate` method returning a boolean value, but I think I need to return either Observable or Promise.

My app has a data store with a property `user` that is an `Observable<User>`.

When the app loads, user.role is `undefined`. After an initial http request, the user.role becomes either "user" or "guest". So, I need the canActivate method to wait until user.role is set to either "user" or "guest", then respond. Here is what I have now:

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<boolean>): void => {
      this.state.user.subscribe((user: User) => {
        if (user.role === 'user') {
          observer.next(true);
        } else if (user.role === 'guest') {
          observer.next(false);
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        // user is not set, wait for next value
      });
    });
  }
```

The problem I think is that the subscription keeps going, and my router is sometimes unexpectedly redirected when state.user is updated. How can I fix this. Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this piece of code

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.state.user.map((user: User) => {
        if (user.role === 'user') {
          return true;
        } else if (user.role === 'guest') {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
        // user is not set, wait for next value
      });
  }
```